Trouble writing and reading from files using threads
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

// Function declarations
void q10();
void *q10gptsin_maclaurin(void *arg);
void *q10gptcos_maclaurin(void *arg);
void q10readfile();

// Global variables
pthread_mutex_t mylock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int flag = 0;

int main() {
    q10();
    q10readfile(); // Read and print the file contents after processing
    return 0;
}

void q10() {
    int choice;
    int file1;
    int closed = -1;
    printf("Enter how many angles: \n");
    scanf("%i", &choice);
    float(*array)[3] = malloc(choice * sizeof(*array));
    for (int i = 1; i <= choice; i++) {
        printf("Enter angle %i \n", i);
        scanf("%f", &array[i - 1][0]);
    }
    file1 = open("/home/endlessparadox/Documents/vs code/angles.dat", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (file1 == -1) {
        perror("open");
        free(array);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < choice; i++) {
        write(file1, &array[i][0], sizeof(array[i][0]));
    }
    close(file1);
    pthread_t sin;
    pthread_t cos;
    pthread_create(&sin, NULL, q10gptsin_maclaurin, (void *)array);
    pthread_create(&cos, NULL, q10gptcos_maclaurin, (void *)array);
    pthread_join(sin, NULL);
    pthread_join(cos, NULL);
}

void *q10gptsin_maclaurin(void *arg) {
    float(*array)[3] = (float(*)[3])arg;
    double sin_value = 0.0;
    double term;
    int n = 0;
    char writeterm[300];
    float buffer;
    int file1;
    int counter = -1;
    ssize_t bytes;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mylock);
    file1 = open("/home/endlessparadox/Documents/vs code/angles.dat", O_RDWR | O_APPEND);
    while ((read(file1, &buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
        counter++;
        sin_value = 0.0;
        n = 0;
        do {
            term = q7gptpower(buffer, 2 * n + 1) / q7gptfactorial(2 * n + 1);
            if (n % 2 != 0) {
                term = -term; // Alternating signs
            }
            sin_value += term;
            n++;
        } while (term > 1e-15 || term < -1e-15);
        array[counter][1] = sin_value;
        printf("Angle: %f Sin: %lf\n", array[counter][0], array[counter][1]);
        snprintf(writeterm, sizeof(writeterm), "Angle: %f Sin: %lf\n", array[counter][0], array[counter][1]);
        write(file1, writeterm, strlen(writeterm));
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mylock);
    flag++;
    if (flag == 1) {
        close(file1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *q10gptcos_maclaurin(void *arg) {
    float(*array)[3] = (float(*)[3])arg;
    int file1;
    int counter = -1;
    ssize_t bytes;
    char writeterm[300];
    float buffer;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mylock);
    file1 = open("/home/endlessparadox/Documents/vs code/angles.dat", O_RDWR | O_APPEND);
    double cos_value = 0.0;
    double term;
    int n = 0;
    while ((bytes = read(file1, &buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
        counter++;
        cos_value = 0.0;
        n = 0;
        do {
            term = q7gptpower(buffer, 2 * n) / q7gptfactorial(2 * n);
            if (n % 2 != 0) {
                term = -term; // Alternating signs
            }
            cos_value += term;
            n++;
        } while (term > 1e-15 || term < -1e-15);
        array[counter][2] = cos_value;
        printf("Angle: %f Cos: %lf\n", array[counter][0], array[counter][2]);
        snprintf(writeterm, sizeof(writeterm), "Angle: %f Cos: %lf\n", array[counter][0], array[counter][2]);
        write(file1, writeterm, strlen(writeterm));
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mylock);
    flag++;
    if (flag == 1) {
        close(file1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void q10readfile() {
    int file1 = open("/home/endlessparadox/Documents/vs code/angles.dat", O_RDONLY);
    size_t bytes;
    char buffer[9999];
    bytes = read(file1, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    buffer[bytes] = '\0';
    printf("Text file contents:\n%s", buffer);
    close(file1);
}

The issue that I have is that, when I input values through the terminal like 3 angles of size (1.0,0.2,0.4) only the 1st angle that was input will be displayed on the terminal with its sin and cos.
I do not understand why it won't process the other angles. Furthermore if I try to read the file using q10readfile(); I just get an empty box.

Begin by not using threads at all. Does it work as expected then? If not then it will be much easier to debug the code.

I also recommend you try to minimize the code, by quite a lot. Perhaps even start over from scratch, with an empty main function. Build with extra warnings enabled and treated as errors. Only when it builds cleanly continue to test the program. When all tests passes then add a very small bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. Build and test again. And so on... When you have a problem, it will be much easier to isolate it into a [mre], and to debug it.

If you're trying to reproduce any bug, whether it's for sharing here or not, it's a good idea to remove any interactive I/O, unless that's specifically what you're testing. Nobody wants to manually input the magic sequence every time they test. Just hard-code it.

@Endless Paradox,  Replace while ((read(file1, &buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) { ... } with while ((read(file1, &buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {  printf("buffer %a %g\n", buffer, buffer); }.  What is that output? As expected?
